# How to turn on/off keyboard lighting on Dell Inspiron via command line

Tags: keyboard, dell

The keyboard lighting doesn't work. I tried using "xset led on", but it doesn't work either. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dell keyboard backlight files/properties are located in `/sys/class/leds/dell:kbd_backlight` in which file named `brightness` has integer value which determine state of keyboard backlight brightness. In my Dell laptop there are 3 states of keyboard backlight.

1. To turn off:

   ```
   echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
   ```
2. To turn on with low brightness:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
   ```
3. To turn on with full brightness:

   ```
   echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
   ```